# Horizontal line spanning the entire document in LaTeX

Tags: rules

I have used the `\hrulefill` command to create a horizontal rule, along with some other commands. In each case I have the rules extended up to the margin.

I want the rule width to be controllable, i.e. I want them to span the entire page. How can this be done? The existing help on Internet looks pretty scarce. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 263):

To get horizontal lines of any fixed length you can use the `\rule` command. To get a horizontal line spanning the whole page width you can use a `\makebox` command and then a `\rule` with a width equal to `\paperwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Below is a Line spanning the entire width of the page

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}

Below is a 2cm long line

\noindent\rule{2cm}{0.4pt}

Below is a 4cm long line

\noindent\rule{4cm}{0.4pt}

Below is a 8cm long line

\noindent\rule{8cm}{0.4pt}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]
Rules in LaTeX are `0.4pt` "thick", by default.

Comment: Maybe you could also include a rule of length `\textwidth`, for comparison with the one of `\paperwidth` placed in a '\makebox`.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to set the top and bottom margin/padding of the line? It could be useful to set the space between paragraphs above and below, respectively.

Answer (score 162):

Another option is this one, which makes a horizontal line stretch the entire page. I prefer this one, because it's short, easy to remember and exactly what I need. I hope this works for you too.

```
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
```

Comment: +1 It helped me to get a gray horizontal line: `\textcolor[RGB]{220,220,220}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.2pt}}`

Comment: Where's the `\noindent`? :-(

Comment: This behaviour is exactly the same as `\noindent\hrulefill`. Sadly, OP wants the line to ignore margin.

Answer (score 20):

I used the `\line` command: `\line(x slope, y slope){length}`.

```
\begin{center}
\line(1,0){450}
\end{center}
```

Comment: It was useful for me to define it as its own command: `\newcommand{\hr}{\begin{center} \line(1,0){450} \end{center}}`.

Answer (score 6):

`\underline{\hspace{ x in}}` gives you a line of length `x` inches.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't be so chatty! ;-) I don't think that this answers the (old) question

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but the most voted answer doesn't really solve the problem.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just to make a smaller picture

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}

\clearpage

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can note that the rule does not cover the whole paper width, because the margins are asymmetric. The trick only works if the margins are equal.

The real solution is very simple: use `2\paperwidth`. The PDF translation will truncate the part that goes beyond the MediaBox. Even better, use `\maxdimen`, so there aren't edge cases for sure.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just to make a smaller picture

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\maxdimen}{0.4pt}}

\clearpage

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\maxdimen}{0.4pt}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Attending the horizontal line problem I used the `\rule` as other has mentioned. Although, if you want to have a centered line that separates your paragraphs you can use this simple code. You can add another `\bigskip` in order to add empty spacing :)

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    
    Some random text above \\
    
    \centerline{\rule{13cm}{0.4pt}}
    \bigskip
    
    Some random text below 
    
    \end{document}
```