# Drawing horizontal line same width as the page width

Tags: margins, rules

I've been trying to draw a line with width the same as the page width. I use `fancyhdr` and I have a line for my footer, and I want the their widths to be equal.

I tried `\line(1, 0){\textwidth}` and `\line(1,0){\pagewidth}` but no luck. I know I can use `\line(1,0){450}` for example, but that means I would have to play around and find the exact page width.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/horizontal-line-spanning-the-entire-document-in-latex

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that the rule is needed in "normal" places of the document, i.e. not in list environments or other special places, the most efficient way is

```
\vskip\medskipamount % or other desired dimension
\leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip0.4pt % or other desired thickness
\vskip\medskipamount % ditto
\nointerlineskip
```

Sensible values for the vertical spaces are `\smallskipamount`, `\medskipamount`, `\bigskipamount` or `\topsep`; it can be given also explicitly.

Such a rule will vanish should it fall at the bottom or at the top of a page, together with the spaces.

Comment: I've seen this answer several times and I like it. It's a clever use of `\leaders`.

Answer (score 13):

To get a line from one margin to the other, use

```
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
```

To get a line from one end of the page to the other, use

```
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt}}
```

Comment: doesn't `\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}` alone works?

Comment: @henrique @yoda `\rule`, if given between paragraphs, adds the normal indent. The use of `\linewidth` is correct and does not give overfull boxes, but it should be `\makebox[\linewidth][r]{...}`.