# beamer full width hrule below frame title

Tags: beamer, rules

I want to create a beamer template with a horizontal rule below every frame title.

The line should start just below the first letter of the title and extend until the very end of the frame.

Desired result:

[image: Frame title with an hrule below spanning to the right end of the frame]

The solution should be flexible enough to handle different font sizes and long titles spanning two lines. However, the vertical position of rule should not adapt to the height of the characters used in the frame title (e.g., whether or not the characters extend below to the baseline).
To clarify:

[image: Vertical alignment of the hrule depending on the characters in the frame title]

To create a `rule` spanning the entire width of the frame, I use `\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}`, as [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19579/53795) by [others](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19903/53795). An undesired side-effect of using `\makebox` is that it behaves differently from `\hrule`, e.g., it has a different height.

I solved the problem of fluctuating positioning of the rule by using `\vphantom{g}` in the frame title, but another solution might be more elegant.

```
\documentclass[t,9pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle%
    \vphantom{g}% To avoid fluctuations per frame
    %\hrule% Uncomment to see desired effect, without a full-width hrule
    \makebox[\linewidth][l]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}% 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Frame contents.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How do I get the desired result of a line below the frame title running until the right end of the frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19904/53795) using `\leaders`, I solved my issue. Additionally, a cleaner solution is to use `\strut` instead of `\vphantom{g}`.

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle\strut%
    \vskip-.25\baselineskip%
    \leaders\vrule width \paperwidth\vskip0.4pt%
    \vskip0pt%
    \nointerlineskip
}
```

Note that I’ve moved the line ¼ `baselineskip` up. This makes the line run over the descenders (that’s actually what I needed).

Answer (score 6):

I understand that you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass[t,9pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle%
    \vphantom{g}% To avoid fluctuations per frame
    %\hrule% Uncomment to see desired effect, without a full-width hrule
    \par% <-- added
    \hspace*{-\dimexpr0.5\paperwidth-0.5\textwidth}% <-- calculation of left margin width
    \rule[0.5\baselineskip]{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title }
Frame contents.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit** If you like to have less vertical space after horizontal rule, than try the following:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle%
    \vphantom{g}% To avoid fluctuations per frame
    %\hrule% Uncomment to see desired effect, without a full-width hrule
    \par\hspace*{-\dimexpr0.5\paperwidth-0.5\textwidth}\rule[0.5\baselineskip]{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}
    \par\vspace*{-\baselineskip}% <-- reduce vertical space after rule
}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Nope, I wasn't looking for the negative `hspace` you added. However, omitting this, your answer solves my question, although I find a solution with `leaders` cleaner.

Comment: I consider the following sentence your question: "To create a rule spanning the entire width of the frame" :(.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I also dislike the fact that I posted a question that I could answer myself in the end, even tough I have been stuck with this problem for quite some time. Still, I greatly appreciate your quick(!) answer.

Comment: It didn't work for me when I also added the command `\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=DarkBlue,bg=White}` :/

Comment: @Dog_69, I haven't a problem with adding this. However, to help you you should add more information, what you do and what was error. But for this is better to ask new question with MWE, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: Dear @Zarko, to be honest, I was hoping that it neither worked for you. I managed to get what I wanted by typing `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{0pt}}{\vspace*{-12pt}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.8pt}}\vspace*{-5pt}}`. The frame title appeared twice with your code. Since my partial solution works fine (so far), I'm not thinking about posting a separate question for the moment, although I might if I found some issues. Thank you for your interest.