# How to create horizontal dashline length of page inside description environment

Tags: pdftex, environments, description, line

I want to create a horizontal dashline with the length of page margin using the `arydshln` package. I've read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19902/drawing-horizontal-line-same-width-as-the-page-width) but when using `\hdashline[1pt/2pt]` I get an error. How should I implement `\hdashline` inside the description environment to get the same result. (It needs to be inside the description environement)

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,comment,arydshln}
\author{something}
\title{something}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{description}
        \item[something] \lipsum[20]
        \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
        \begin{comment}
            need a dashline here but I don't know how to implement \hdashline[1pt/2pt] here. Moreover, I need the line to cover the page from margin to margin. This doesn't achieve this
        \end{comment}
        \item[something] \lipsum[20]
    \end{description}
    \lipsum[20]
\end{document}
```

I've realized that I can use `\hdashrule[0.5ex][c]{\linewidth}{1pt}{2pt}` But this doesn't cover the page from margin to margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain it with the `dashrule` package and a simple `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,comment, dashrule}
\author{someone}
\title{something}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \begin{description}
        \item[something] \lipsum[20]
        \vspace{-1ex}\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\hdashrule[1ex][x]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}{1pt 2pt}}
        \item[something else] \lipsum[20]
    \end{description}
    \lipsum[20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `\leaders` and `\hfill` you can create a dashed line yourself. We have to skip to the left margin ourself because else the line would start at the indented width of the description text (hence we use `\hskip\itemindent`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,comment,arydshln}
\author{something}
\title{something}
\newcommand*\descriptiondashsep
  {%
    \par\noindent
    \hskip\itemindent
    {\leaders\hbox{\rule{2pt}{.4pt}\hskip1pt}\hfill\hskip-1pt}%
    \null
  }
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{description}
  \item[something] \lipsum[20]
  %\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
  \descriptiondashsep
  % need a dashline here but I don't know how to implement \hdashline[1pt/2pt]
  % here. Moreover, I need the line to cover the page from margin to margin.
  % This doesn't achieve this
  \item[something] \lipsum[20]
\end{description}
\lipsum[20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Greatly appreciate it.