# Best alternative to toprule outside table environment

Tags: tables, rules

Here is a repro for my problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm,
    left=2.5cm,
    right=2.5cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\toprule
\vspace{7pt}
Foo
\vspace{7pt}
\toprule
\end{document}
```

This gives me an error on both `\toprule` lines:

```
Misplaced \noalign
```

However, overleaf still compiles and displays the PDF (which I don't really understand):

[image: using toprule]

As best I can tell, it's because I'm using it outside the context of a tabular environment.

But how can I achieve exactly the same effect outside a table?

I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19582/151707), which leads to code like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm,
    left=2.5cm,
    right=2.5cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\vspace{7pt}
Foo \\
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\end{document}
```

But this does not align the line vertically in the same manner:

[image: using rule]

Can anyone tell me how to do horizontal ruling in the same manner *outside* a table as in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `tabularx` environment which allows to declare the final width of your tabular (`\linewidth` in this case).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm,
    left=2.5cm,
    right=2.5cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l}
\toprule
Foo \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how would I add space above and below "Foo" so the lines aren't so close?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I can use `\addlinespace[20pt]`

Answer (score 1):

see if this gives expected result:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\noindent\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
Foo\\
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:**
with use of `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{mybox/.style={%
colback=white,
boxrule=0pt,
colframe=black,
toprule=1pt, bottomrule=1pt,
boxsep=0mm,
arc=0mm,
left=0pt,right=0mm,top=3mm,bottom=3mm,
}}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{mybox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{mybox}
Foo
\end{mybox}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost, but how do I push the bottom `rule` down further? The top `rule` specifies `1ex`, but that's to control added space below the `rule`. How do I control space above the rule? Adding `vspace` seems to just push stuff down that is _after_ the `rule`, not the `rule` itself.