# A better way to number lines with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-numbering

I've managed to number a series of lines in a page (as in an exam sheet) using tikz, but it feels awkward and somewhat sketchy. Is there any way to improve it or make it "cleaner" (with or without other packages)?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}%showframe
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{lineno}

\newcounter{linha}
\newcommand{\linha}{\stepcounter{linha}\arabic{linha}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,1.7,...,26}
\draw (0,\x) -- (16,\x);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\foreach \x in {25.25,24.55,...,0.3}
%\foreach \y in {1,...,26}
\node at (-0.8,\x) {\linha};
\end{tikzpicture}




\end{document}


\documentclass[border={5pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\foreach \x in {1,...,5}
\draw[line width=\x mm] (0,\x) -- (2,\x);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, if you don't mind, what is your purpose here ?

Comment: @BambOo, simple exam answer sheet with numbered lines.

Comment: Does the numbering  stand for answer numbering ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this approach, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19582/141947).

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}%showframe
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\foreach \nline in {1,...,21}{
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could do with less packages: `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\newcounter{nline}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers\setcounter{nline}{0}\loop%
\stepcounter{nline}\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
\ifnum\value{nline}<21\repeat
\end{document}`.

Comment: This is great. I have not found the `\nline` command anywhere in the `tikz` documentation. Where does it come from?

Comment: @Joseph This is just the loop variable. You may replace it by whatever macro you like, e.g. `\CuteFurryRodent` will also work.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, nice to know. I didn't know a random undefined variable was somehow needed if it isn't called back later. By the way, `\CuteFurryRodent` sounds nice.