# Basic answer sheet ready for handwriting

Tags: paper

I want something as follows:

[image]

I tried it with `$\hline$` and some text but getting some errors. I'm almost a beginner in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{black}}



\begin{document}
    Problem: \underline{\hspace{30pt}}
    \hfill
        Page \underline{\hspace{30pt}} of \underline{\hspace{30pt}}
    
    
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @TobiBS Added my work. Those packages aren't really used, though

Comment: This may help u: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/horizontal-line-spanning-the-entire-document-in-latex

Comment: Do you just want something like `Problem: \underline{\hspace{30pt}}` ?

Comment: You can try also with a table.

Comment: @IanThompson Thanks, that works. Also, how can I remove the page number at the bottom? I looked through some answers TSE but they don't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\rhead{}
\lhead{Problem : \underline{\hspace{30pt}} \\ Page \underline{\hspace{15pt}} of \underline{\hspace{15pt}}}
\cfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\begin{document}
Problem 01: Evaluate the following integral : $$\int_1^e \left(\ln x\right)^2 dx$$
\end{document}
```

I used the `fancyhdr` package to write on the head of the page, and according to @lanThompson comment I used the following `\underline{\hspace{30pt}}`.
[image]

As I said, I'm not satisfied with the blank space, meaning I don't know how to make that line, I used only the comment of @lanthompson!

Comment: Thank you! Could you please add the commands to remove the page number at the bottom? I really need this.

Comment: @VIVID All that you need to do is to replace `\cfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}` with `\cfoot{}`