# LaTeX \paperwidth is arguing

Tags: pdftex, errors, pdf, compiling, compilation-error

### I wanted to make a *horizontal* separator in **LaTeX**

So i used this piece of code(as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/horizontal-line-spanning-the-entire-document-in-latex)):

`\noindent\mathmakebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}`

The strange thing that it's **properly** displaying after compiling it to the PDF but in *compile time it is **arguing***.

> I am using Visual Studio Code and `MikTeX`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What do you mean with 'arguing'? Do you get an error or warning? If yes, what is the exact message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The command `\mathmakebox` is provided by `mathtools` and can only be used in math formulas, not in plain text.

Comment: if asking about an error message always show the exact message, copied from the log file

Answer (score 1):

The code in the quoted answer has `\makebox`, not `\mathmakebox`, which is a command that can only be used in math mode (and requires `mathtools`).

They're *not* interchangeable. You get two error messages about `missing $ inserted`, one when `\mathmakebox` is not encountered in math mode and one when closing the box.

Note that `\makebox` *can* be used in math mode, but its contents is typeset in text mode, so the commands have very different purposes.

However, you should use

```
\noindent\makebox[\columnwidth]{\rule{2\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
```

or `\maxdimen` instead of `2\paperwidth` as I showed in the answer I added in that old thread.